# tabularx adds empty column when left alignment is set

Tags: tables, tabularx

I want to create a table with four columns, in which the first column contains row spans and the cells `\verb`s.

Here is the code:

```latex
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}l}

.
.
.

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{4}{Y|}}
\hline
Category & Interface & Signature & Method \\ 
 \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Predicate} & \verb|Predicate<T>| & \verb|T -> boolean| & \verb|.test(T t)| \\ \cline{2-4}
& \verb|BiPredicate<T, U>| & \verb|T, U -> boolean| & \verb|.test(T t, U u)|\\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Consumer} & \verb|Consumer<T>| & \verb|T -> void| & \verb|.accept(T t)|\\ \cline{2-4}
& \verb|BiConsumer<T, U>| & \verb|T, U -> void| & \verb|.accept(T t, U u)|\\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
```

In the result, a fifth column gets added:

[image]

At the beginning, `\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}l}` had a X instead of a l, which works, but I need the left alignment, because otherwise the first column is too big and the other cells start to overflow:

[image]

Why does LaTeX add this fifth column?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: The issue you've come across is an artifact of the improper definition `\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}l}`. The issue vanishes if you switch to `\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}`.

Comment: In this case the left alignment is gone; I added a screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two separate issues with the definition

```
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}l}
```

*First*, this definition doesn't actually do anything useful. Indeed, the OP might as well have written

```
\newcolumntype{Y}{l}
```

since LaTeX cannot flexibly adjust the width of an `l` (or `c` or `r`) column. The improper definition is the direct cause of the presence of what the OP calls a "fifth column" in the table. This "fifth column" is an artifact of (a) the horizontal lines generated by `\hline` occupying the full width of the text block and (b) the combined width of the four cells falling short of `\textwidth`.

What the OP maybe *meant to* write is

```
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
```

as that'll make the "fifth column" disappear on its own. However, this suffers from a *second problem*, since -- based on a comment provided by the OP -- the OP does *not* actually want to center-set the cell contents. I can only assume that what the OP really wants is to typeset the cell contents in ragged-right mode; the basic `X` column type applies full justification to the cell contents.

If this assumption is correct, one should write

```
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
```

This fixes the phantom fifth column issue *and* left-aligns the cell contents.

However, there's an additional, entirely separate problem with the "look" of the table: its multitude of vertical lines and poorly-spaced horizontal lines make the table look like a **dreary prison window**. To fix this aesthetic issue, I suggest omitting all vertical lines and using the macros of the `booktabs` package -- `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\cmidrule`, and `\bottomrule` -- instead of `\hline` and `\cline`.

The three outcomes are illustrated in the following screenshot.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\usepackage{tabularx,multirow}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}l}   % <-- inappropriate
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X} % what the OP (probably?) wants

\usepackage{booktabs} % new, for well-spaced horizontal rules

\setlength\textwidth{13cm} % just for this example
\setlength\parindent{0pt}  % just for this example

\begin{document}

OP's setup: improper column type, and unattractive ``prison window look.''

\smallskip
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{4}{Y|}}
\hline
Category & Interface & Signature & Method \\ 
 \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Predicate} & \verb|Predicate<T>| & \verb|T -> boolean| & \verb|.test(T t)| \\ \cline{2-4}
& \verb|BiPredicate<T, U>| & \verb|T, U -> boolean| & \verb|.test(T t, U u)|\\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Consumer} & \verb|Consumer<T>| & \verb|T -> void| & \verb|.accept(T t)|\\ \cline{2-4}
& \verb|BiConsumer<T, U>| & \verb|T, U -> void| & \verb|.accept(T t, U u)|\\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip
Preliminary fix: use the correct column type. However, ``prison window look'' persists.

\smallskip
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l| *{3}{L|}}
\hline
Category & Interface & Signature & Method \\ 
 \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Predicate} 
   & \verb|Predicate<T>|      & \verb|T -> boolean|    & \verb|.test(T t)|      \\ 
   \cline{2-4}
   & \verb|BiPredicate<T, U>| & \verb|T, U -> boolean| & \verb|.test(T t, U u)| \\ 
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Consumer}
   & \verb|Consumer<T>|       & \verb|T -> void|       & \verb|.accept(T t)|      \\ 
   \cline{2-4}
   & \verb|BiConsumer<T, U>|  & \verb|T, U -> void|    & \verb|.accept(T t, U u)| \\ 
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip
Full fix: Employ a much more open ``look'' by omitting all vertical lines and using only well-spaced horizontal lines.

\smallskip
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l LLL @{}}
\toprule
Category & Interface & Signature & Method \\ 
\midrule
\multirow{2.3}{*}{Predicate} 
   & \verb|Predicate<T>|      & \verb|T -> boolean|    & \verb|.test(T t)|      \\ 
   \cmidrule(l){2-4}
   & \verb|BiPredicate<T, U>| & \verb|T, U -> boolean| & \verb|.test(T t, U u)| \\ 
\midrule
\multirow{2.3}{*}{Consumer}
   & \verb|Consumer<T>|       & \verb|T -> void|       & \verb|.accept(T t)|      \\ 
   \cmidrule(l){2-4}
   & \verb|BiConsumer<T, U>|  & \verb|T, U -> void|    & \verb|.accept(T t, U u)| \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

- Unfortunately you not provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), wo used document class as well your documents pages layout are unknow.
- Use of the `tabularx` table at least one column had to be of `X` type.
- See, if the following solution (used`article document class) gives what you after:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
    \setlength\tabcolsep{5pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X |l|l| l|}
    \hline
Category    & Interface                 & Signature                 & Method \\
    \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Predicate}              
            & \verb|Predicate<T>|       & \verb|T -> boolean|       & \verb|.test(T t)| \\ 
    \cline{2-4}
            & \verb|BiPredicate<T, U>|  & \verb|T, U -> boolean|    & \verb|.test(T t, U u)|\\ 
    \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Consumer} 
            & \verb|Consumer<T>|        & \verb|T -> void|          & \verb|.accept(T t)|\\ 
    \cline{2-4}
            & \verb|BiConsumer<T, U>|   & \verb|T, U -> void|       & \verb|.accept(T t, U u)|\\ 
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addedndum:**
you can get a simpler and shorter table's code and a nicer table looks by using the `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {X[l] *{3}{Q[l, font=\ttfamily]}},
             colsep  = 5pt,
             row{1}  = {font=\normalfont}
             }
Category    & Interface         & Signature         & Method            \\
\SetCell[r=2]{l}    Predicate              
            & Predicate<T>      & T -> boolean      & .test(T t)        \\ 
            & BiPredicate<T, U> & T, U -> boolean   & test(T t, U u)    \\ 
\SetCell[r=2]{l}    Consumer 
            & Consumer<T>       & T -> void         & .accept(T t)      \\ 
            & BiConsumer<T, U>  & T, U -> void      & .accept(T t, U u) \\ 
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, working as intended. Will keep in mind to add a MWE next time.

Comment: @Ceriana, you are welcome!! See addendum to my answer, you may liked it :-)